# How to solve a number which is raised to a large number?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I easily evaluate a number which is raised to a very huge number?

For example; Is there an easy way to evaluate $2^{100}$ ($2$ raise to the power $100$)? It will get very messy and difficult if i open all the $2$s and then evaluate it. So, how to do it easily?

Comment: What do you mean solving a number?

Comment: There are methods for finding the number mod $n$ which are simple enough if $n$ is considerably smaller than 100.

Comment: @Danny Cheuk. I mean to open the value. For example; 2^4 will give 16.

Comment: @MuhammadRafique : Solve is the wrong word here.  People not adept in the terminology of mathematics often use that word as a catch-all term when they're not sure what the right word is.  In this case "evaluate $2^{100}$" would be appropriate.

Comment: Do you mean actually computing $2^{100}$ or perhaps $2^{100}$ modulo something reasonably small? The first is a mess to do by hand, the second not as bad.

Comment: thanks @MichaelHardy. Eddited it.

Answer (score 2):

By "solving," I'm going to assume that you mean "writing it in closed form." One way to do it with fewer exponentiations is by successive squaring:

\begin{align}
2^1 &= 2\\
2^2 &= 4\\
2^4 &= 16\\
2^8 &= 256\\
2^{16} &= 65536 \\
2^{32} &= \,\,\,...
\end{align}

and so on. Then use the fact that $2^{100} = 2^{64 + 32 + 4}$, and only three multiplications must be done at this stage.